# Passing App object to function / class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, facade

I'm working with Laravel 4.2, calling a payment flow between form submit and the controller response. If the payment is accepted, a bunch of work is done behind the scene by the class PaymentProcessor

```
use MyProject\libraries\payment\PaymentProcessor;

class MyFirstController extends \Controller {

    protected $paymentProcessor;

    public function __construct(
        PaymentProcessor $paymentProcessor
    ) {
        $this->paymentProcessor = $paymentProcessor;
    }

    public function postFormSubmit() {
        //DO SOME STUFF
        $paymentResult = $this->paymentProcessor->makePayment($paymentDetails);
    }
}
```

PaymentProcessor is on a different namespace, and I'm able to call a needed library using App::make

```
<?php namespace MyProject\libraries\payment;

use MyProject\DataObjects\PaymentDetails;

class PaymentProcessor {

    public function makePayment(PaymentDetails $paymentData) {
        $doFirstStep = \App::make('amazingLibrary')->doImportantThings();
```

but, for testing purposes I want to remove all instantiations and calls to other classes directly from PaymentProcessor, so I've tried to do the following injection:

```
<?php namespace MyProject\libraries\payment;

use MyProject\DataObjects\PaymentDetails;

class PaymentProcessor {
    private $app;

    public function __construct(\App $app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }
```

And tried:

```
    public function makePayment(PaymentDetails $paymentData) {
        $doFirstStep = $this->app::make('amazingLibrary')->doImportantThings();
```

But it leads to:

**FatalErrorException (E_PARSE) syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)**

Am I in the right way?

Update:

I've also tried to call it as: `$this->app->make`

That leads to:

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::make()**

Comment: Comment out private app property. I want to see the next result

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: `$this->app::make()` is invalid code. When using `::` you have to qualify it with the name of the class that the method belongs to (e.g. `SomeClass::make()`.

Comment: This is a bad idea - you are trying to inject your whole application into your tiny module - think about, read about `SOLID`, spe `Dependency Injection` and redesign. For the `::` - right way is `$this->app->make` since you already instantiated this object, and `::` is namespace (scope) resolution operator, so you use it to indicate, what (static) method / property you'd like to use.

Comment: I don't see as duplicate since the referred question is not talking about my injection doubts. T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM is only one of the 2 errors I've exposed, and the reffered question shows how to call static methods but didn't solve my problem. @Marcin Nabiałek perceived it and came with a very objective answer, different of all 7 from the other question, and solved my problem.

Comment: @AndréTeixeira That's probably because of your question title. I've changed it and nominated this question for reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want to do something like that:

```
something($app);

function something (\Illuminate\Foundation\Application  $app) {

    echo  $app->getLocale();
}
```

So in your case you need to use `$this->app->make` syntax and you need to pass parameter as I showed (and $app is instance of `\Illuminate\Foundation\Application` not `\App`)

Comment: That's it! Still not sure if it is the best approach, but now able to evaluate both solutions.